# Python: sort a list of tuples by item frequency

Tags: python

Say I have a list:

```
tmp = [((0,0), (1,1)), ((1,2), (3,4)), ((1,2), (5,6))]
```

And I'd like to sort it such that it's ordered by the most frequent pair, where "most frequent pair" is defined by the frequency of each pair's tuple in the first position:

```
>>> [((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (5, 6)), ((0, 0), (1, 1))] # desired
```

1) I tried a simple expression with `lambda`, but was **unsuccessful**:

```
tmp = sorted(tmp, key = lambda x: -tmp.count(x[0]))
```

2) I managed to achieve the desired results by using `collections.Counter`:

```
c = collections.Counter(x[0] for x in tmp)
tmp = sorted(tmp, key = lambda x: -c[x[0]])
```

My question: why was approach 1) incorrect? And is there a better option than approach 2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [54]: tmp = [((0,0), (1,1)), ((1,2), (3,4)), ((1,2), (5,6))]

In [55]: counts = collections.Counter(t[0] for t in tmp)

In [56]: sorted(tmp, key=lambda t:counts[t[0]])
Out[56]: [((0, 0), (1, 1)), ((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (5, 6))]

In [57]: sorted(tmp, key=lambda t:counts[t[0]], reverse=True)
Out[57]: [((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (5, 6)), ((0, 0), (1, 1))]
```

Your first approach was incorrect because `x[0]` does not exist in `tmp`. Rather, it exists in a tuple that exists somewhere in `tmp`

I've improved your second approach just a little. It takes away from having to multiply by `-1`

---

I really wouldn't recommend this, but if you really wanted to make your first approach work, you could count all the tuples which have `x[0]` as the first element:

```
In [58]: sorted(tmp, key=lambda t:len([tup for tup in tmp if tup[0]==t[0]]), reverse=True)
Out[58]: [((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (5, 6)), ((0, 0), (1, 1))]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how come I can do something like this?
`>>> tmp = [(3,4), (1,2), (5,6)]`, `>>> sorted(tmp, key = lambda x: x[0])` and not succeed with the first approach?

Comment: checked! Thanks G4dget!